# ¿Cómo usar efectos como los de JQuery en Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs-2.0

¿Cómo puedo hacer, para que los componentes de la página, respeten los efectos que les doy?
Ejemplo: Yo tengo una div, que contiene un botón, al cual si lo pulsas, se le ha asignado una función, que cambiará el valor de una variable, para que la información de ese div se despliegue debajo de él.

```
<div class="divListProyect">
                <div class="proyectSpecifics">
                    <h1>{{video.name}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="proyectListButtonContainer">
                    <a class="btn" (click)="mostrarInfo(video._id)" >Ver más info.</a>
                    <a class="btn" (click)="guardarInfo()" >Ver menos info.</a>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/video-update', video._id]" class="btn">Editar</a>
                    <a (click)="onDeleteVideo(video._id)" class="btn" >Borrar</a>
                    <div *ngIf="confirmed == video._id" class="divDeleteBtns">
                        <span>¿Seguro que quieres borrar el registro?</span>
                        <a (click)="onDeleteConfirm(video._id)">Aceptar</a>
                        <a (click)="onDeleteCancel()">Cancelar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

y luego, el div que desplegaría sería éste:

```
    <div class="proyectInfo" *ngIf="info == video._id">
        <h1>{{video.name}}</h1>
        <p><strong>Descripción: </strong>{{video.description}}</p>
        <p><strong>Duración: </strong>{{video.duration}}</p>
        <p><strong>Medios usados: </strong>{{video.tecnologies}}</p>
        <p><strong>Autor: </strong>{{video.author}}</p>
        <div *ngIf="video.file != null || video.iframe != null">
            <video class="videoDetail" *ngIf="video.file && video.file != null" src="{{url + 'getVideoFile/' + video.file}}" controls>Tu navegador no implementa este elemento.</video>
            <iframe class="iframeDetail" *ngIf="video.iframe && video.iframe != null" [src]="safeUrl(video.iframe)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pretendo hacer, que cuando el div se despliegue, lo haga con algún efecto del estilo a `"toggle()"` de la librería JQuery, pero al parecer no me lo respeta.

Comment: efecto lo da jquery con bootstrap generalmente, deberias de instalar ngx-bootstrap, si tienes que actualizar tu repo por que es muy viejo deberias de probar con ng2-bootstrap

Comment: Qué quieres decir con "efectos"?

Comment: Usar por ejemplo toogle(). No lo respeta, aparece el div sin el efecto. Esos componentes tampoco respetan por ejemplo, el tiempo de transición de CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

En general es una mala idea mezclar Angular con jQuery: hace el código más complejo y suele ser más sencillo usar las librerías de angular para obtener el mismo resultado. En el caso de las animaciones, [angular2+](/questions/tagged/angular2%2b)<sup>1</sup> provee de Angular [animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations).

Por tanto, si simplemente quieres ocultar un elemento, usa ngIf* que directamente lo eliminará si la condición no se cumple. Si quieres ocultarlo con una transición, entonces usa el atributo `[hidden]="condicion"` y una animación, algo como lo que se ve en [este ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qS9Va2uxDb4KOpOQcNO5?p=preview).

<sup>1</sup>Aprovecho para proponer este tag en lugar del confuso [angularjs-2.0](/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)